# How to change font size on part of the page in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I would like to change the text size for some page part, e.g. for a verbatim block:

```
\begin{verbatim}
    <how to set the font size here to 10 pt? />
\end{verbatim}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
\begingroup
    \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{verbatim}  
        % how to set font size here to 10 px ?  
    \end{verbatim}  
\endgroup
```

Comment: The first parameter to `fontsize` is the font size to switch to and the second is the line spacing to use

Answer (score 61):

Example:

```
\Large\begin{verbatim}
   <how to set font size here to 10 px ? />
\end{verbatim}
\normalsize
```

`\Large` can be obviously substituted by one of:

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

If you need arbitrary font sizes:

- [How can I get an arbitrary font size in LaTeX?](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907396)

Comment: Is there a way to provide exact size ?

Comment: Keep in mind that this goes against the spirit of LaTeX.  Why do you want an exact size, anyway?

Comment: @Arafangion, how can I get familiar with the spirit of it? I will appreciate if you provide some references

Answer (score 14):

The use of the package `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` allows the definition of the fontsize argument inside Verbatim:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
print "Hello, World"
\end{Verbatim}
```

The fontsize that you can specify are the common

```
\tiny 
\scriptsize  
\footnotesize 
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

Answer (score 5):

To add exact fontsize you can use following. Worked for me since in my case predefined ranges (Large, tiny) are not match with the font size required to me.

```
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont This is the text you need to be in 10px
```

More info: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-3/tb105thurnherr.pdf

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting

use `\alltt` environment instead. Then set size using the same commands as outside verbatim environment.