# Latex - how can I make a text to stand out more?

Tags: latex

I'm designing my diploma thesis and would like to make a big question mark to every problem and a exclamation mark to every solution. It should like like this:

[image: My dream design]

Do you know any Latex-Libraries to accomplish that behaviour? If there is no such library I would be more than happy if you could help me getting started writing my own Latex-Command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one basic approach.  No packages are involved.

A particular thing about your layout is the use of the margin, correlated with that line of text.  One way about it is to define a simple environment, which uses Latex command for margin notes, `\marginpar`.  Then you can also set up fonts as you please, within this environment.  Below I also insert an unrelated margin note, as an example in case you are not familiar with those.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newenvironment{Q} {\hspace{\stretch{1}} \Huge} {\marginpar{ \Huge{?} } \newline}
\newenvironment{A} {\hspace{\stretch{1}} \Huge} {\marginpar{ \Huge{!} } \newline}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Some text ... Margin note entered {\em here} \marginpar{NOTE} ... more text \\
\vspace{0.5in}

\begin{Q} Here is a question \end{Q}
State your question ... \\

\begin{A} This is an answer \end{A}
Go with the answer ... \\

New paragraph, for other text ...

\end{document}
```

See [this page in Latex Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments) for a very clear explanation of how to define a new environment. If you end up wanting more control see the package [environ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ).

Margin notes provide you with a few options.  If you want to reverse the logic of where they are placed, use `\reversemarginpar`. You can also set up different text to appear depending on which margin the note goes in by using `\marginpar[left text]{right text}`. See the Wikibooks article on [footnotes and margin notes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes), which spells out where notes go based on the document type.

Here are some posts for more specialized uses: on [notes in both margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101553/margin-notes-on-both-left-and-right), and on [notes in narrow margnins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230753/how-to-use-marginpar-with-narrow-margins). For doing far more with margin notes see package [magrinnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote), and there are yet other packages, like [todonotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes?lang=en). See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes) for a visual show off of what it can do.

I've used a basic way to change font size, and no special symbols.  A list of these fonts can be found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40725/how-to-change-the-font-size-during-the-new-defined-environment), for example. You can use very particular fonts and/or symbols if you like, which are convenient to set up in the new environment. See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220371/how-to-change-font-size-on-part-of-the-page-in-latex), which also has another way of formatting for your Q&A. Also informative may be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220371/how-to-change-font-size-on-part-of-the-page-in-latex).

Note that you can also use existing environments inside this new one, if you wish.  You can also set up a counter, and have an ability to cross-reference these. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21227/example-environment) for an example.

[image: margin_QA]

Comment: Thanks, one quick follow-up question: How do I position the question/exclamation mark AND the text on the left side? I played around with hspace and stretch, but it's not working the way I want.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, my code now looks like this:
    \newenvironment{Q} {\LARGE\noindent} {\marginpar{ \Huge{?} } \newline}
[This](https://i.imgur.com/bFEBOYn.png) is the output. What exactly do I have to change to align the question mark to the left side of the text?

Comment: @Philipp  Huh? That's a surprise ... try either `\ignorespaces` as shown in the Wikibooks link for environment, or the `\flushleft`.  I can't test anything right now, will see how to do this when I get on the computer with latex.  Also, any other environment can be in there, like `\quote`, but I wanted to keep it 'simple'.  Need to try it out (unless the above works out for you).

Comment: The alignment of the text + the alignment of the questionmark works like a charm! The only thing that could be improved is removing the heavy whitespace between the question mark and the header. [As you can see here more clearly](https://i.imgur.com/MwRqLed.png) Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @Philipp  Yet another option is to put the `\hspace{\stretch{1}` after the text you want, which will push the text all the way to the left.  You do that by putting it in the 'after' block -- `\newenvironment{Q} {\LARGE\noindent} {\hspace{\stretch{1}  \marginpar{ \Huge{?} } \newline}`.  (The first `{}` are done before, and the second `{}` after the text in the environment is processed.)  I can't test this now though, sorry.

Comment: Just tried your code, there isn't changing anything :(

Comment: @Philipp  **This refers to previous comment, with picture**  That is because the text inside `\marginpar` is flushed left.   The `\marginpar` is a mini-paragraph, with text being formatted pretty much like it is a normal paragraph.  So force it right -- it should work with the same `\hspace{\stretch{1}}` **BEFORE** the `?`, to force it to the right.

Comment: Now it's working, many thanks! You were extremely helpful, THANK YOU!