# Changing math formulas font size in RPres

Tags: r, latex, mathjax, rpres

How can I change the font size of the the math formulas in Rpres? [Editor's note: 'Rpres' is the file extension used by RStudio for its "Presentation" files. It's apparently been adopted by users as shorthand for that section of the IDE.]  A similar problem is faced in [Code box size and font size in RPres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612385/code-box-size-and-font-size-in-rpres), but it does not solve the problem with math formulas, that are not part of a chunck of code separated from the text, but are a chunk of LaTeX code.

Please consider, for example, this section of a slide produced with the default setup:

```
The average height is 175cm, with a standard deviation of 10. 
The z-score for a student 163cm is given by the formula:

$$z = (x - \mu)/\sigma$$

where $x$ is the student of our interest, $\mu$ is the distribution mean of
the school and $\sigma$.
```

Returns:

[image]

Sure enough, the approach suggested in [Code box size and font size in RPres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612385/code-box-size-and-font-size-in-rpres) does not affect the size of the math formulas.

Comment: @42- Hi, are you sure the question is a duplicate? I edited the question to better explain my point.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Is it then a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220371/how-to-change-font-size-on-part-of-the-page-in-latex? No... that didn't succeed. Probably not real Latex. Need to narrow the search to markdown methods.

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274501/r-markdown-changing-font-size-and-font-type-in-html-output

Comment: I solved the problem. Math formulas are chunks of Latex code, hence I used `\Huge my_text` to change the font size. Thank you for your suggestion. Do you think that is better if I close the question?

Comment: I went on a search and found this page: http://www.martinkeefe.com/math/mathjax9 which I was going to use as the basis of an answer. You should instead write up an answer and then give yourself a check (after the appropriate waiting period) for a useful, correct answer. I'll add my upvote to your answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Math formulas in RPres documents and Rmarkdown documents are LateX chunks of code embedded in the Rmarkdown document.

Hence, the font size of a math formula or, more generally, of LaTeX text, can by modified with an argument ranging from `\tiny` to `\HUGE`:

```
$$\Huge textblog.org$$
```

will affect the size of the font according to:

[image: img1]

Comment: I would like to thank @42- for the valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It also works for me as
$$\Huge z = \frac{x}{y}$$